# Getting error BXNUI2081E while uploading certificate files to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am getting the following error while trying to upload SSL certificates to IBM Cloud Bluemix. It happens both with the web GUI and CLI

```
Uploading certificate to domain 'xxxxx.co'...
FAILED
Error response from server. Status code: 500; description: BXNUI2081E: <b>The certificates and keys were not modified because an unknown error occurred: Error.</b> <br>Click the <b>Account and Support</b> icon in the top menu bar, click <b>Get help</b>, and search for help or get support..
```

What might be the reason and the solution?

Comment: I would open up a support ticket here: https://console.bluemix.net/unifiedsupport/tickets/add The support team may need a bit more information to help assist you.

Comment: @joe strangely the error disappeared after a day.